# How to troubleshoot cartodb windshaft?

Tags: carto, windshaft

I installed CartoDB on a digital ocean instance of Ubuntu 12.04. I am able to log in and import data. Table view is fine, but map view does not show tiles with the message "There is a problem with your connection". I assume this means  problems with the Windshaft tile server.

Windshaft installs ok:

```
git clone git://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft-cartodb.git
cd Windshaft-cartodb
git checkout master
npm install
```

but `make check` fails; nine failing tests with two primary errors:

```
AssertionError: "2.1.0" == "2.1.1"
```

and

```
Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:769:11)
    at HTTPServer.Server._listen2 (net.js:909:14)
    at listen (net.js:936:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:993:9)
    at dns.js:71:18
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

The only thing I changed in config/environment/test.js was to set Mapnik version to 2.1.1.

I've posted the full output of `make check` here:
http://pastebin.com/CWSfijR8

Any ideas on what I'm not configuring or installing correctly? Or how else to troubleshoot these errors?

(follow up and update from question originally posted in [CartoDB google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cartodb/ssy6T1wt22k))

Comment: could you check the result of echo "keys rails:users*" | redis-cli -n 5

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I get: ```1) "rails:users:carto"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapnik version error was a bug in the testsuite, which wasn't expecting anyone to change mapnik_version in the test.js configuration file.

Thanks for spotting it, now fixed :)

https://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft-cartodb/commit/ae82d0ab47d21a8e5aef7f332b74244d94072545

Answer (score 0):

The EADDRINUSE indicates that you're trying to use a port that is being used by something else.  I wouldn't worry about the make check command.  What happens when you try to run Windshaft? Are you still getting the errors?

```
node app.js <env>
```

Where env is the name of a configuration file under config/environments/ (minus the extension).

If you're still getting EADDRINUSE errors, you may need to change the port Windshaft listens on.  Also, keep in mind that if you're not running Windshaft as  root, you won't be able to run it if it is using a port less than 1023.

Comment: no errors when running Windshaft with node app.js; also no errors using foreman, but still no tiles. I don't see any obvious errors in the terminal, any other error logs I should look for?